# Discord.py command not working without any error messages or output

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is the code that until I ran it today when this command didn't provide any feedback, no embed, no error message and no new files:

```
@bot.command(name="start")
async def some_crazy_function_name(ctx):
        global currentcreator
        if not currentcreator == 0:
                await message.channel.send("Someone is already making a profile, please wait")
        currentcreater = ctx.author
        dir = r'C:\\Users\\FiercePC\Desktop\DiscordMMO\User-Profiles'
        MessageAuthor = str(ctx.author.id)
        ProfileDIR = os.path.join(dir,MessageAuthor)
        doesExist = os.path.exists(ProfileDIR)
        if doesExist == False:
                embed=discord.Embed(title="Creating Profile", url="", description=MessageAuthor+", your profile is being created", color=0x3b05ff)
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                os.makedirs(ProfileDIR,1)
                
                file = os.path.join(ProfileDIR,"Hitpoints.txt")
                open(file,"x")
                openfile = open(file,"w")
                openfile.write("3")
                openfile.close()
                
                file = os.path.join(ProfileDIR,"MaxHitpoints.txt")
                open(file,"x")
                openfile = open(file,"w")
                openfile.write("3")
                openfile.close()
                
                file = os.path.join(ProfileDIR,"HitpointsEXP.txt")
                open(file,"x")
                openfile = open(file,"w")
                openfile.write("0")
                openfile.close()
                
                file = os.path.join(ProfileDIR,"StrengthEXP.txt")
                open(file,"x")
                openfile = open(file,"w")
                openfile.write("0")
                openfile.close()
                
                file = os.path.join(ProfileDIR,"StrengthLevel.txt")
                open(file,"x")
                openfile = open(file,"w")
                openfile.write("1")
                openfile.close()
                
                embed=discord.Embed(title="Profile Created", url='', description=MessageAuthor+', thanks for setting up your profile, now you can enjoy a unique MMO RPG experience only on discord.', color=0x3b05ff)
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)   
                currentcreator = 0
```

I haven't changed anything that would make it not run properly so I am so confused why entering my command prefix / and then start wouldn't do anything. I even deleted the existing files from a previous test to see if it just saw the existing files so didn't send anything but it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I eventually fixed it, turns out that my pc was pre built by Fierce PC which makes it pre come with 1 visible FiercePC user and 1 hidden FiercePC user. The code decided to save the files to the hidden user which I didn't previously know existed

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a on_message event running? if so, that could make the command not work.

Comment: Im not using on_message, i am using the proper bot syntax that only checks messages with the prefix, using on_message slows down your bot a lot

Comment: Is the code you provided the only command that doesn't  work?

Comment: Yeah, i tested all my other commands and they work fine

Comment: Although you probably already did this, check to make sure its indentation level is not in another function. Also, where did the 'message' variable on line 5 come from cause when I ran it it says that there was no variable named message

Comment: Message is part of the discord python module, not a variable

Comment: I was telling you the error that I received when I ran it. In this context, message has not yet been defined. instead of `message.channel.send()` do `ctx.message.channel.send()` The message is the message that the user sent to call a command, you still have to get the message from somewhere and you would do this by using `ctx.message`.